# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: no session or session was closed

Tags: java, hibernate

I am specifying my entity as follows

```
 package com.drishti.training.dbentity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.drishti.dacx.core.framework.ameyoentitytypes.AbstractDBEntity;

/**
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "template")
public class TemplateDBEntity extends AbstractDBEntity {

    String template_name, organisationId;

    @Column(name = "organisation_id", nullable = false)
    public String getOrganisationId() {
        return organisationId;
    }

    public void setOrganisationId(String organisationId) {
        this.organisationId = organisationId;
    }

    private String templateId;
    //    private List<Integer> listOfTrainingIds;

    private List<String> listOfTrainingIds;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "template_id", nullable = false)
    public String getTemplateId() {
        return templateId;
    }

    public void setTemplateId(String templateId) {
        this.templateId = templateId;
    }

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "template_id_vs_training_id", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "template_id"))
    @Column(name = "training_id", nullable = false)
    public List<String> getListOfTrainingIds() {
        return listOfTrainingIds;
    }

    public void setListOfTrainingIds(List<String> listOfTrainingIds) {
        this.listOfTrainingIds = listOfTrainingIds;
    }

    @Column(name = "template_name")
    public String getName() {
        return template_name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.template_name = name;
    }
}
```

and

another table is

```
create table template_id_vs_training_id
(
    template_id varchar references template(template_id) on delete cascade,
    training_id varchar references training(training_id) on delete cascade,
    PRIMARY KEY (template_id,training_id)
);
```

but when i load the TemplateDBEntity it provides me the above reported error.

Comment: any specific reason for using CollectionTable

Comment: also share the code for repository/querying

Answer (score 7):

[LazyInitializationException](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/LazyInitializationException.html), as hibernate documentation says:

> Indicates an attempt to access not-yet-fetched data outside of a
>   session context. For example, when an uninitialized proxy or
>   collection is accessed after the session was closed

The only cause of this exception is `listOfTrainingIds` property as it's an 
[@ElementCollection](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) which is Lazy loaded by default, so either :

- Make sure that you're accessing `listOfTrainingIds` property inside a transaction (Your entity can use available session to fetch your collection).
- Or make it eager `@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, but be aware that every time your select the entity from the database, your collection will be loaded eagerly as well, even if you don't need it, which can impact performance.
- Or use [fetch](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins) keyword in your hibernate Query (if you're using query to load your entity):

```java
    List<TemplateDBEntity> TemplateDBEntitys = session.createQuery(
    "select t from TemplateDBEntity t join fetch t.listOfTrainingIds", 
    TemplateDBEntity.class).getResultList();
```

- Or use [@FetchProfile](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/FetchProfile.html).

```java
    // In class...
    @FetchProfile(
      name = "withListOfTrainingIds",
      fetchOverrides = {@FetchProfile.FetchOverride(mode = FetchMode.JOIN, association = "listOfTrainingIds", entity = TemplateDBEntity.class)})
    public class TemplateDBEntity extends AbstractDBEntity {
      //...
    }

    // To get your entity
    session.enableFetchProfile("withListOfTrainingIds");
    System.out.println(session.get(TemplateDBEntity.class, templateId));
    session.disableFetchProfile("withListOfTrainingIds");
```

I prefer the last two options, as hibernate will perform one query to database, even you keep the collection lazy loaded, which is better for performance.